# Double column float number with IEEEtran and dblfloatfix

Tags: floats, two-column

`dblfloatfix` allow to place floats at the bottom of the page, however if by lack of chance there is another float on the same page, the correct numbering is not achieved (i.e. the double column float number is lower than the one of the other float on the same page). Is there an easy fix? Or only a workaround with manual setting of the float number (with `\renewcommand\thefigure{x}` for example)?

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,conference,twocolumn]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[cmex10]{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{dblfloatfix}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-5]

\begin{figure*}[b] % will appear at the bottom of the next page
\centering
  \includegraphics{Some-image-1}
\caption{A caption}
\end{figure*}

\newpage

\begin{figure}[t]
\centering
  \includegraphics{Some-image-2}
\caption{Another caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: maybe loading the package `fixltx2e`helps, as described here: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions#Wide_figures_in_two_column_documents

Comment: @Faekynn no :-(

Comment: Looks like not without a reasonably large amount of work, much of what fixltx2e/dbfloatfix does isn't needed in latex 2015 release anyway as the fixes are included by default, but the addition of bottom 2 col floats doesn't seem to take account of the numbering/. rather than redefine `\thefigure` I'd use `\setcounter{figure}{2}` just before the `\caption` to force it to be figure 3.

Answer (score 2):

LaTeX had a longstanding bug (or rather, documented deficiency) that the numbering of double column floats could get out of sequence with single column floats. There were packages available to address this, and form the 2015 LaTeX release onwards the fix was included in the format by default.

However the bottom float addition added here is based on the earlier code and so gets out of sequence. Updating it to match the new code would be relatively involved and for a single document it is easier just to correct the numbering as below, forcing the value of the `figure` counter for the floats that swapped position, making sure to reset it back to normal at the end so later floats get the correct automatic numbering.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,conference,twocolumn]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[cmex10]{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{dblfloatfix}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-5]

\begin{figure*}[b] % will appear at the bottom of the next page
\centering
  \includegraphics{Some-image-1}
\setcounter{figure}{1}
\caption{A caption}
\end{figure*}

\newpage

\begin{figure}[t]
\centering
  \includegraphics{Some-image-2}
\setcounter{figure}{0}
\caption{Another caption}
\setcounter{figure}{2}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: *documented deficiency* :)

Comment: Thanks. Using `\addtocounter` would be slightly more generic in case other figures are added before this page. Specifically, `\addtocounter{figure}{1}\caption{First figure}` ... `\addtocounter{figure}{-2}\caption{Second figure}\addtocounter{figure}{1}`.